# Wie sagt man "to redo one's nails" auf Deutsch?

Tags: word-usage, verb

> Morgen werde ich meine Nägel in Ordnung bringen lassen.
>
> Tomorrow I will redo my nails.

In meinem Wörterbuch sagt, dass "to redo sth" "etwas in Ordnung bringen" ist, aber ich weiss nicht, ob ich dieses in diesem Kontext verwenden kann.

Comment: Was ist denn damit gemeint? Maniküre? Nagellack erneuern?

Comment: … Entrosten von Kleineisenwaren?

Comment: Ich finde hier klingt die freie Übersetzung besser: "Morgen werde ich (wieder) zur Maniküre gehen. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falls damit Metallstifte gemeint sind, würde man die nicht *in Ordnung bringen*, sondern würde das etwas konkreter formulieren:

> Morgen werde ich meine Nägel entrosten.
>   Morgen werde ich meine Nägel gerade biegen.

Ich vermute aber, dass hier Fingernägel gemeint sind. Auch hier würde ich das konkreter formulieren:

> Morgen werde ich meine Fingernägel pflegen.
>   Morgen werde ich meine Fingernägel lackieren.

Natürlich kann man »Fingernägel« durch »Nägel« ersetzen, wenn der Kontext eine Verwechslung mit Metallstiften ausschließt.

Auf keinen Fall kann der englische Satz aber so übersetzt werden, dann man die Erneuerung/Verbesserung von jemand anderem vornehmen lässt. Das vorgeschlagene Wort »lassen« am Ende des Satzes ist also falsch.

Anders wäre es bei diesem englischen Satz:

> Tomorrow I will get my nails redone.
>   Morgen werde ich meine Fingernägel pflegen lassen.

Comment: Ach komm, du waschechter Österreicher ;-) Wer würde denn bei uns seine Nägel *'pflegen'* - Vielleicht *'generell'* oder *'grundsätzlich'* gesagt kann man so förmlich daherlabern - aber wir würden doch 10x eher sagen, dass wir uns unsere 'Nägel richten/herrichten (lassen)'... ;-)

Comment: @mramosch: Wenn man etwas richtet, dann repariert man es. Wenn jemand bittet »Kannst du mir bitte mein Moped richten?« dann will man keine gründliche Reinigung oder Neulackierung, sondern eine Reparatur. Das gilt auch für Fingernägel. Wenn man die *richtet*, dann bessert man abgebrochene Stellen aus. Ich glaube nicht, dass das mit »redo my nails« gemeint ist. Ich glaube, dass damit das normale Schneiden, Feilen und/oder Lackieren gemeint ist, und das ist keinesfalls »richten«. »Herrichten« passt auch nur begrenzt, denn das verstehe ich primär als »vorbereiten«, nicht so sehr als »behübschen«.

Comment: Eigentlich heißt *'redo'* -> eine bereits getätigte Handlung nochmals tun: ***'redo one's hair'*** - *'sich nochmals frisieren'*. In diesem Sinne hier eher *'wieder in den gewünschten Original-/Ausgangs-/Normalzustand zu bringen'*. Wie eben auch für *'Daten wiederherstellen'* -> also einen ungewünschten Zustand wieder *'zurecht rücken'* oder *'reparieren'*, wenn Du es so ausdrücken willst... - Und das selbe gilt für *'kannst du mir bitte meine Nägel herrichten'* - sei es für *'feilen, zurecht schneiden oder eben auch lackieren!

Answer (score 3):

Typisch wäre:

> Morgen werde ich mir die Nägel (neu) machen (lassen).

Auf Deutsch *macht* man sich die Nägel. Bei "in Ordnung bringen lassen" klingt es so, als wollte ich nicht wissen, wie sie zur Zeit aussehen.

Comment: Das ist aber schwer Deutschland-Deutsch ;-) Euch tut anscheinend die Nähe zu Frankreich nicht ganz gut ;-)))

Comment: Klingt mir eher nach *'Kunstnägel'* die abgebrochen sind und die man sich dann auch wieder neu machen lassen muss. Die OP klingt mir eher nach den *'originalen'* Nägeln...

Comment: "Nägel machen lassen" hat in meinen Ohren Großstadtghettoscharm